# Tidyverse update and rlang - code not longer working

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, slice, rlang

I have this simple piece of code:

```
  restockingPh3NSmax_rho<-c(0,1,20)
    restockingPh3BSmax_rho<-c(0,1,20)
    restockingPh3ESmax_rho<-c(0,1,20)

    CtrolScenRho<-as.data.frame(crossing(restockingPh3NSmax_rho,restockingPh3BSmax_rho,restockingPh3ESmax_rho))

    CtrolScenRho<-CtrolScenRho%>%slice(-c(1:4,6:8,10,12,15:20,22:24,26))
```

This code was working until Yesterday. Today, I updated Tidyverse and this code no longer works. I get the following error:

> Error in slice_impl(.data, dots) :    Evaluation error:
>   `as_dictionary()` is defunct as of rlang 0.3.0. Please use
>   `as_data_pronoun()` instead.

I have a lot of code written using Tidyverse coding approach that may not be working. Please, I need to fix this. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved.

The solution requires updating both R and R studio, then reinstalling Tidyverse